# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start_time' of undefined

Tags: javascript, object

I am receiving the following error: backend_calendar_default_view.js?52FX8:1107 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start_time' of undefined

I am not able to get rid of this error and it is making no sense to me.
Please have a look at what is being printed out in the image attached.

I see no reason why the code should fail as the expected results is being written to the console:
[image]

```
var countarray = countsarray.find(x => x.start_time === currentLabel.start);
console.log(countarray);
console.log(countarray.start_time);
console.log(countarray.count);
console.log(parseInt(labelNumberString));
//myArray.findIndex(x => x.id === '45');
var labelint = parseInt(labelNumberString);
var count1 = countarray.count;
labelNumberCount = labelint - count1;
```

I know that this may be something silly I am doing wrong but any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Regards,
LJR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line
`var countarray = countsarray.find(x => x.start_time === currentLabel.start);`
cannot find a value x for which `x.start_time === currentLabel.start` then it will return undefined.

You can add a check to see if it's undefined before doing something with this `countarray` value.

```
if (countarray !== undefined) { 
  //do stuff with countarray here
}
else {
  //do stuff if the value wasn't found
}
```

Comment: Helpful and to the point - thank you soooo much! Changed it to this: 
Have a NaN error now, but i'll figure that out. Thanks again ! :)